# Thread safe queue gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I'm writing a thread safe queue to add stringstream objects. I thought that the segmentation fault was happening because `stringstream ss` gets destroyed when added to the queue but as you see I'm moving it with `std::move()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue
{
public:
    /* 
        Returns the front element and removes it from the collection
        No exception is ever returned as we garanty that the deque is not empty
        before trying to return data.
        This is useful in our while loop renderer, because it just waits if there
        are no members to be popped.
    */
    T pop(void) noexcept
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};

        while (_collection.empty())
        {
            _condNewData.wait(lock);
        }
        auto elem = std::move(_collection.front());
        _collection.pop();
        return elem;
    }
    template <typename... Args>
    void emplace(Args &&... args)
    {
        addDataProtected([&] {
            _collection.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        });
    }

private:
    /*
        Locks the thread and do something with the deque. 
        Then unique_lock goes away and unlocks the thread
    */
    template <class F>
    decltype(auto) lockAndDo(F &&fct)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
        return fct();
    }

    template <class F>
    void addDataProtected(F &&fct)
    {
        lockAndDo(std::forward<F>(fct));
        _condNewData.notify_one();
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> _collection;            // Concrete, not thread safe, storage.
    std::mutex _mutex;                    // Mutex protecting the concrete storage
    std::condition_variable _condNewData; // Condition used to notify that new data are available.
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ThreadSafeQueue<std::stringstream>> logMessages;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello";
    logMessages->emplace(std::move(ss));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jweyrich I don't think so. I don't have compilation errors, but runtime errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<ThreadSafeQueue<std::stringstream>> logMessages;
```

You never allocated memory for this variable.  It's not pointing to a `ThreadSafeQueue<>` object

Maybe

```
auto logMessages = std::make_unique<ThreadSafeQueue<std::stringstream>>();
```

instead?

or just make the plain object as suggested in the comments.

Comment: This may be a a simplified example, but there's a strong case here for not using a pointer at all. Why not give `ThreadSafeQueue<std::stringstream> logMessages;` a shot?